# How to measure time of multiple commands in background?

Tags: scripting, background-process

I have a shell script with multiple commands and I want to run each command in background, so I put an & at the end of each command. I need to measure how much time execution of all the commands takes in total. How can I do that?

P.s. Commands might take minutes to run.

Answer (score 1):

Add `wait` at the end of shellscript, and start as `time ./myshellscript`